# Simple Logon System using Membership provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have a website which requires pretty simple logon restriction to a set folder (2 users) I'd like to use the Membership provider but have a sql DB (While easy and painless) seems a bit of overkill.

Is there a simpler way of doing this? without re-writting the membership provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I've decided the best way is to use the SQL database and standard tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your web.config to store your members and roles definitions/credentials.
A sample here: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20060529.asp

Answer (score 0):

You could hard code the password hashes for the 2 users into the asp files and match the hash at logon :)

Comment: hard-coding is not a good practice. should only be used in tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET WebPages ships with a simple membership (membership + roles) that is targeted at your senario check out more details on my blog post about it: http://blog.osbornm.com/archive/2010/07/21/using-simplemembership-with-asp.net-webpages.aspx